# How to use sharepoint 2007 contents data in new one sharepoint 2013 site structure .

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How to use sharepoint 2007 contents data in new one sharepoint 2013 site structure ?. which way we used so that sp2007 content data used new sp2013 without migration?. if we create a web services so it is good or not ? please suggest me. how can achive this .

Comment: Yes best option is Web services so you create a webservice in sharepoint 2007 and get list ,library data , timer job, list definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes best option is Web services so you create a webservice in sharepoint 2007 and get list ,library data , timer job, list definition.